# Boost directory iterator throwing ERROR_INVALID_DRIVE

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I observe boost (v. 1.64) directory iterator constructor (`directory_iterator(const path& p)`) throwing an exception with ERROR_INVALID_DRIVE on a windows system. I suppose the problem happens on NTFS, but can't be 100% sure.

1. What are general reasons for ERROR_INVALID_DRIVE?
2. What may be throwing it inside `directory_iterator(const path& p)`? From my understanding, it just lists a directory, so can't meke up a way to get an invalid drive here

UPDATE:

Here is the relevant code:

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

bfs::path cache_path("C:/Users/Администратор/AppData/Local/some_unique_path/");

long long dir_size = 0;

boost::system::error_code ec;

int err_no = 0;

for (bfs::directory_iterator it(cache_path), eit; it != eit; it.increment(ec)) {
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "Error " << 0 << ":" << ec << " while clearing the cache\n";
        return;
    }

    dir_size += bfs::file_size(it->path(), ec);

    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "Error " << 1 << ":" << ec << " while clearing the cache\n";
        return;
    }
}

dir_size >>= 20; // want current cache size in Mb

if (dir_size > new_size) {
    std::cout << "Clearing the kernel cache..." << std::endl;
    // each file is attempted to be removed
    for (bfs::directory_iterator it(cache_path), eit; it != eit; ++it) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Error " << 2 << ":" << ec << " while clearing the cache\n";
            return;
        }
        bfs::remove(it->path(), ec); // this ec is skipped: don't care if it was impossible to delete file
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the source code for boost. Simply step into it until you get to the likely internal (win32/crt) function which fails. Work out what parameters are being passed into that and go look up the documentation for that function. If that doesn't work, edit the question with those details and we may be able to help.

Comment: @MikeVine, unfortunately, I don't have a way to debug it directly, as it happens on the machine I have no access to, so it's a guessing game, sorry for asking to play it with me. I've updated my question with all the code related to boost:filesystem module I have. Maybe, it would help to help.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice to see a piece of your code. Usually this means that directory does not exist. Be noted that in Windows directory paths have the following format, for example, `"C:\dir1\dir2"`. It is hard to help you since you did not provided any source code sample. Maybe you just provided path with wrong format.

Comment: I just thought that adding a call to constructor won't help much, but ok, I've added all the code, related to boost filesystem, I have. Note the string, which is used to initialize ```boost::filesystem::path```. It uses backslashes. I thought that windows is able to handle them, doesn't it?

Comment: About backslashes, I think it's IDE dependent. Have you tried just to replace all `"/"` with `"\"` ? I think that's the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "IDE dependent"? Unfortunately, I cannot just substitute, as it happens on the machine I have no access to, but as I see from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm#Grammar, boost should handle backslash separators on windows, or do I mistake the docs?

Comment: I mean some IDEs using their "root" directory same as the source file's directory, others use one directory higher. See, you can't directly access directories straight from `C:/` location since your program does not know about that. Try to use some directories that are local to your source files like `/` or `../`.